# SQL to generate report of entity-attribute-value structured data

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables:

Productmaster:

```
ProductId    PName     PDescription
```

Attributes:

```
AttributeID  attName
----         ----
1            Brand
2            Category
3            Artist
```

ProductAttributeValues

```
paId   ProductId  AttributeID AttributeValues
```

A `product` can have multiple `attributes`.

Here's the desired output:

```
ProductId  ProductDesc  Brand    Category    Artist
---        ---          ---      ---         ---
1          sadasd       Brand1   Category1   Artist1
2          sadasds      Brand2   Category3   Artist4
```

How can I get this output?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What RDBMS? What is expected output? What SQL are you running?

Comment: What were you able to achieve from your attempts... can you post your 'almost-there' query.. I'll try and help you iron out the kinks.

Answer (score 1):

You should left join for each attribute value you want to pull in, e.g.

```
select p.ProductId,p.ProductDesc,
a1.AttributeValues as Brand,
a2.AttributeValues as Category, 
a3.AttributeValues as Artist,
from Product p
left join ProductAttributeValues a1 on(p.ProductId=a1.ProductId and a1.AttributeID=1)
left join ProductAttributeValues a2 on(p.ProductId=a2.ProductId and a2.AttributeID=2)
left join ProductAttributeValues a3 on(p.ProductId=a3.ProductId and a3.AttributeID=3)
```

To turn this back into English, "give me all products, and for each one, give me a brand, category and artist attribute if they exist"

I've assumed that a product has only one or zero values for each attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Assumed that every attribute appears exactly once per product:

```
SELECT 
  pm.ProductId as ProductId,
  pm.PDescription as ProductDesc,
  pav_Brand.AttributeValues as Brand,
  pav_Category.AttributeValues as Category,
  pav_Artist.AttributeValues as Artist
FROM
  ProductMaster pm
    inner join ProductAttributeValues pav_Brand 
      on pm.productId == pav_Brand.ProductId
    inner join Attributes a_Brand 
      on pav_Brand.AttributeId = a_Brand.AttributeId
        AND a_Brand.attName = 'Brand'
    inner join ProductAttributeValues pav_Category 
      on pm.productId == pav_Category.ProductId
    inner join Attributes a_Category 
      on pav_Category.AttributeId = a_Category.AttributeId
        AND a_Brand.attName = 'Category'
    inner join ProductAttributeValues pav_Artist 
      on pm.productId == pav_Artist.ProductId
    inner join Attributes a_Artist 
      on pav_Category.AttributeId = a_Artist.AttributeId
        AND a_Brand.attName = 'Artist'
```

You can use left outer joins if the data is not always available.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query, maybe some tweak required

```
Select pm.ProductId, pm.PDescription, pav1.AttributeValues, pav2.AttributeValues, pav3.AttributeValues 
from Productmaster pm, ProductAttributeValues pav1, ProductAttributeValues pav2, ProductAttributeValues pav3 
where pm.ProductId = pav1.ProductId 
and pav1.AttributeID = 1 
and pm.ProductId = pav2.ProductId 
and pav2.AttributeID = 2 
and pm.ProductId = pav3.ProductId 
and pav3.AttributeID = 3
```

Comment: Thanks Ian, could you please tell me how to get that scrolling fram for the code. Is there any link on website which talks about this and other useful tid bits.

Comment: @Bhushan - Highlight the code and above the post text box there is an icon with binary in it. That sets the text to "code". If you hover over each of the icons you can get a tooltip of what each one is.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  ProductId, ProductDesc,
        (
        SELECT  AttributeValues
        FROM    ProductAttributeValues pv
        WHERE   pv.AttributeID = 1
                AND pv.ProductID = p.ProductID
        ) AS Brand,
        (
        SELECT  AttributeValues
        FROM    ProductAttributeValues pv
        WHERE   pv.AttributeID = 2
                AND pv.ProductID = p.ProductID
        ) AS Category,
        (
        SELECT  AttributeValues
        FROM    ProductAttributeValues pv
        WHERE   pv.AttributeID = 3
                AND pv.ProductID = p.ProductID
        ) AS Artist
FROM    Products p
```